# How do I move an object back and forth with touch in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to move an image back and forth based on the user's finger. I want to be able to touch the screen and then the image will move towards my touch. The image should only move left to right not up and down and I would also like to add limits to how far the image can go towards one side of the screen.

I know this sounds like a lot but I have tried many things all of which have caused problems. The first time I was able to click and drag the image which is good but when I clicked somewhere else the image would just appear there it wouldn't move there it just appeared.

The second thing I tried allowed me to drag the image but when I clicked out of the image it wouldn't move towards the finger at all. At this point I'm very frustrated and would appreciate any help. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Person: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ){
          let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)




            if Person.frame.contains(location){
                Person.center = location
            }
        }
    }


    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ){
            let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)




            if Person.frame.contains(location){
                Person.center = location
            }
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you *edit* your question to show the code for your attempt(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using `touchesBegan(_:withEvent:)` and `touchesMoved(_:withEvent:)` to get the touch events. These methods give you a `UITouch` which you can convert to a `CGPoint` using `locationInView(_:)`.

When a touch begins (i.e. `touchesBegan(_:withEvent:)`), you should animate your custom view to the `CGPoint` of the touch. E.g.:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

    // Only adjust the x, not the y, to restrict movement to along the x-axis.
    // You could also check the x value of point to see if reached some limit.
    self.squareView.frame.origin.x = point.x
})
```

When a touch moves (i.e. `touchesMoved(_:withEvent:)`), you should set the custom view's location to the `CGPoint` of the new touch. E.g.:

```
// Only adjust the x, not the y, to restrict movement to along the x-axis.
// You could also check the x value of point to see if reached some limit.
squareView.frame.origin.x = point.x
```

Some suggestions

1. Only use the first `UITouch` from the set of touches, so you can get rid of your for-loop.
2. The line `if Person.frame.contains(location){` is wrong because it is only moving the `Person` if the touch is within the `Person`'s frame, remove this and set the frame's origin with the `UITouch`'s point (or animate it using my code above).

Comment: I have added my code to make things more clear.

Comment: How should I directly implement this into my code?

Comment: I added some suggestions in my answer.